# Is ESC involved in any key combinations?

Tags: key-bindings, escape, control-character

Just starting to get into Vim and facing the classic escape problem. I'm thinking binding <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to be <kbd>control</kbd> when used with another key, and <kbd>escape</kbd> when released without pressing anything else would be a great solution.  However, I don't want to do that if escape is used in some important key combinations.

Comment: Esc *itself* is a combination: Ctrl-[

Comment: for terminals, yes, like e.g. Cursor Key movement, Alt-Key combinations, and various other ones I do not currently remember.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt in those cases, it's not a combination, but a sequence, right?

Comment: @muru yeah that is true.

Comment: @muru so are you saying it's a totally safe bind?

Comment: Yes. A combination usually involves keeping one key pressed while pressing others, and that only when one of the keys is a modifier, like Ctrl, Super, Meta, etc. Keeping Esc pressed is just going to generate a sequence of Escs. (You can't have a combination of, say `a` and `b`, for example, or `Enter` and `Tab`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, when you write "combination", you are referring to when two keys are pressed simultaneously (sometimes also called "chords" by analogy with musical terminology), then <kbd>Escape</kbd> *cannot be used* in such combinations and thus you're safe to rebind your <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key in this way.

Note that hundreds* of other Vim users (including me) already do this with no ill effect other than the fact that it becomes more difficult to use other people's computers once you get used to it. It's for this latter reason that I'm not sure if I'd *recommend* you do this, but it's totally fine to do so, at least as far as Vim is concerned.

<sub>* Thousands? Millions?!?</sub>

Comment: @me in your second paragraph. I love my control key (it happens to say CapsLock, but whatever). However, nobody else has one like it, and typing on their keyboards is annoying!